# How to catch XmlSerializer Object in managed CPP that is returned from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, managed-c++

I have one C# DLL in which one method is returning XmlSerializer Object.

This DLL I am using in my Managed CPP programme. And from CPP I am calling C# method that is returning XmlSerializer Object. Please let me know how to catch this returned XmlSerializer Object in managed CPP.

E.G : 
    C# Method :

```
XmlSerializer xmlTables1 = bc.ReadTablesXml(string company, string language, string servername, string config);
```

How can I call above method from managed CPP? And how to catch the returned XmlSerializer object in CPP?

Comment: Are you actually using managed C++ (VS2002)? Or is it possibly C++/CLI?

Comment: Assuming by "catch" you mean "assign" and not `catch` and assuming `bc` is a managed pointer to something then `XmlSerializer ^xmlTables1 = bc->ReadTablesXml(company, language, servername, config);`

Comment: yes I am using managed C++ (VS 2008)

Comment: To use XmlSerializer  what should i include in the header ..for example " using namespace System; "

Comment: It's at the top of the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx